How to disable rebasing in Source tree
i had recently run below command
git config --global pull.rebase true

after this Sourcetree was by default asking me to rebase everytime i take a pull, now to disable this rebasing in Sourcetree, also i tried to set rebasing as false but it still don't work.
git config --global pull.rebase false

Anyone have any solution for this?

To disable rebasing in Sourcetree go to Settings > Advanced > Edit Config File, at the end of the file you will see below code:
[pull]
        rebase = true

Change true to false and restart Sourcetree. After that you won't see the rebase option while pulling
